# Is a functor returned by boost::bind with only bound arguments equivalent to a function that takes no arguments?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

Suppose an API requests, that a function `f` must have the signature `void function()`. Does the following code sample satisfy this requirements?

```
 void func(int i)
 {
       do_something(i);
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    int i = 3;
    auto f = boost::bind(func, i);
 }
```

With other words: does `f` in this case meets the requirements of the given API?

**EDIT:** My question was a bit vague on the term "function". For clarification: `f` shall be function-like, so a simple function or a function object. The concrete case why I was asking this question came up, when I worked with strands in Boost.ASIO. [Here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand/post/overload1.html), the documentation says for a possible handler for `strand::post`:

> The function object to be called. The executor will make a copy of the handler object as required. The function signature of the function object must be: `void function();`

So: is `f` from the above example a function object with the correct signature for `strand::post`?

Comment: in c++11 you can skip boost::bind and write `auto f = [i] {func (i);};`

Comment: Does the API require a function or a function like thing?  For instance would `struct dummy { void operator() {} };` wotk?

Answer (score 2):

> is f from the above example a function object with the correct signature for strand::post

Yes, the functor returned by `std::bind` is a valid functor to `io_service::strand::post`. `std::bind` exists for such purposes, it binds paramaters with values and reduces its count to satisfy requirements of API.

Comment: most modern APIs (eg stl) can accept either a function pointer or a functor

Comment: @user463035818 OP definitely says that API requests a function.

Comment: @user463035818 So any answer would be correct. If somebody writes yes, I vote up the answer.

Comment: @user463035818 Yes, we agree that the answer is no. If OP asks such question, I deduce that OP means a pointer to a function and OP ran into a problem.

Comment: @user463035818 I have updated my answer after OP's updated the question.

Comment: I would still critize the same (you use "API" as if there would be only one API but you are refering specifically to whatever API OP is talking about), but still nevermind, it wont change anything essential on the answer, I will just delete the spammy comments

Comment: @user463035818 Sorry, I supposed the OP is a newbie, its profile reports only 4 questions and 0 answers, thus I assumed OP deals with pointers only.

Comment: @S.M. I do always feel like a newbie in C++. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No, because `std::bind` [returns an unspecified object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).</strike> It is required to have cetain members and methods but that's about it. If the exact return type doesn't matter much then perhaps it meets the requirements, but strictly speaking it's not a function.

Edit:

After clarification in the question the answer is strictly *yes* as this unspecified object is required to behave the way that `strand::post` requires.

Comment: Since the clarification of the question this answer is no longer correct. The answer to "With other words: does `f` in this case meets the requirements of the given API?" is strictly "yes" here.